# Sort Product Sorting on Drag & Drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, redux

I have implemented *react-beautiful-dnd* to drag & drop elements inside of a table.

Now I am not sure how to dispatch into the backend the information so that the sorting persits.

When I am done dragging, it fires an event that returns an array but I am not sure how to dispatch this array into the backend.

I was thinking about creating an UpdateAllProduct Router/Action but it doesn't feel like good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `order` property that holds order of the array. Then you can update your database according to `order` property.

Comment: it does the job thanks :)